# How can I render and output data table in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I have been trying to implement a data table library in my react application. I keep having a runtime error : Text strings must be rendered within a  component. 
This is part of my code where I'm trying to implement the data table.
I have tried to use other libraries but the same error has popped up.
Is it wrong to try to output the data table in render()?
The original code contains other parts like dropdown and piechart where they both worked normally in render().
Update: 
These are the screen shot of two different error I got while trying to output the data table. I hope they help to clarify the porblem.
[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l5z3.png)  [second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggoj1.png)

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import AweIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {Button} from '../components';
import ipAddress from '../ipAddress';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Table from 'rc-table';

export default class Result123 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    const columns12 = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        width: 100,
      },
      {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
        width: 100,
      },
      {
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
        key: 'address',
        width: 200,
      },
      {
        title: 'Operations',
        dataIndex: '',
        key: 'operations',
        render: () => <a href="#">Delete</a>,
      },
    ];

    const data12 = [
      {name: 'Jack', age: 28, address: 'some where', key: '1'},
      {name: 'Rose', age: 36, address: 'some where', key: '2'},
    ];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>THE LATEST 20TH VOTE RECORDS</Text>
            <Table columns={columns12} data={data12} />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  horiView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  heading: {
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 17,
    color: 'black',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
  },
  card: {
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
    width: '90%',
    height: 250,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#dddddd',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: Is this all the code for this part? The error is coming from <Text> tags.

Comment: @yuRa yes, this is all the code thats relevant to the data table. My guess is that react doesnt allow me to output string directly and has to be a <Text> component inside the render().

Answer (score 0):

Check logical conditional renders in your original code. it might be the issue.
example, if you use this,

```
{somvariable && <Text></Text>}
```

and your variable is an empty string, then this error will be thrown. make sure your variable is null before checking like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I did not use any logical conditional renders.

Comment: My guess is that react doesnt allow me to output string directly and has to be a <Text> component inside the render(). I think i need a way to turn my json data into <Text> component? I'm not sure, I'm new to react. Feel free to correct my approach.